# Shopify webhook gets called twice

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I have created an `APP_SUBSCRIPTIONS_UPDATE` webhook. When I install an app and upgrade the first plan to the second plan, the webhook is run only 1 time. But after that when I upgrade or downgrade the app subscription plan, the webhook is run twice on each plan change event. here is [shopify doc link](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/enums/WebhookSubscriptionTopic#value-appsubscriptionsupdate) and [webhook log](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/23345371?key=547e24954cb3be5a79f339c01ab5c844)

here is [shopify-app.php](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/23346484?key=80984c9fa7df96f90d11aaeb940119b4) and [job file](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/23346485?key=41d4f7f9c91905992b1eaab46d98557e).

Comment: There is nothing you can do about Shopify sending you multiple webhooks for the same event, all you can do is take this into account, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we upgrade or downgrade an app subscription plan that time if there is no previous activated plan then Shopify only sent one webhook with ACTIVE status. if there is a previously activated plan then Shopify sent two webhook one for the CANCELLED plan and one for a newly activated plan.

Comment: and apparently the CANCELLED webhook can come after the ACTIVE webhook right, or so close together in time that their order is random? albeit with different GIDs